# grep items with special symbols

Tags: r, extract, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am trying use `grep` to extract item that contains symbols`_` and `|`. When I tried to `grep` with exact match, it returned all items. How to solve the problem?

```
string = c("ny_(apple)|store", "mn_(apple)|store", "ok_(apple)|store")
grep("\\ny_(apple)|store\\>", string) #this failed because it returned all three items
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (double) backslash escapes:

```r
grep("ny_\\(apple\\)\\|store", string)
#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

On my MacOS Terminal using single quotes worked. `grep 'seachText'` worked.